# How do I pass a mutable list to a bundle?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, bundle, mutable

I want to add a mutable list to a bundle, but there doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish this.

```
var bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.put...????("LIST", fbModel.recipeArray)
```

You can use `putString` and so on, but there doesn't seem to be a `putMutableList` as an option. What to do?

***UPDATE***
Forgot to mention that the `mutableList` recipeArray is an `object`. Like this:

```
var recipeArray: MutableList<RecipeTemplate>
```

...where RecipeTemplate is a class that looks like this:

```
class RecipeTemplate {
    var recipeHeader: String? = null
    var recipeText: String? = null
    var recipeImage: String? = null
    var recipeKey: String? = null
}
```

***UPDATE***
Solved issue according to answer by @EpicPandaForce:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                Log.d("TAGA", "CLICKETICLICK " + position)
                Log.d("TAGA", "CLICKETICLICK " + fbModel.recipeArray[1].recipeHeader) //PASSES

                val intent = Intent(classContext, Recipes::class.java)

                var bundle = Bundle().apply {
                    putParcelableArrayList("LIST", ArrayList<Parcelable>(fbModel.recipeArray))
                    putInt("POSITION", position)
                }

                intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

But I'm still having problem receiving it in the other activity. Code here from onCreate:

```
var passedIntent = intent.extras
var bundle: Bundle = passedIntent.getBundle("bundle")
var counter: Int = bundle.getInt("POSITION", 0)
var recipeArray: ArrayList<Parcelable> = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("LIST")
var recipeList: MutableList<RecipeTemplate> = recipeArray as MutableList<RecipeTemplate>

Log.d("TAGA", "PASSED " + counter) //PASSES
if(recipeArray != null) {
    Log.d("TAGA", "HERE " + recipeArray[1].recipeHeader.toString()) //Null
    Log.d("TAGA", "HERE " + recipeList[1].recipeHeader.toString()) //Null
    Log.d("TAGA", "HERE " + recipeArray.size) //PASSES

}
```

The `counter` is passed and the correct number is shown. The `recipeArray.size` is passed and shows the correct number. However, the other logs `recipeArray[1].recipeHeader.toString()` and `recipeList[1].recipeHeader.toString()` are both null even though they contain the correct values before being put in the bundle. Is there something I need to do to... eum... de-parse the list? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `RecipeTemplate is a class.` might wanna be more specific

Comment: OK, updated with class info :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do

```
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' 

//androidExtensions {
//    experimental = true
//}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

Then

```
@Parcelize
class RecipeTemplate : Parcelable {
    var recipeHeader: String? = null
    var recipeText: String? = null
    var recipeImage: String? = null
    var recipeKey: String? = null
}
```

Then

```
var bundle = Bundle().apply {
                  putParcelableArrayList("LIST", ArrayList<Parcelable>(fbModel.recipeArray))
             }
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. I also added `@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")` above `@Parcelize` to silence an error. Only problem now is to get it back to it's original state when unpacking from bundle, right? I can't seem to use it as it is in new activity...

Comment: Use `getParcelableArrayList<RecipeTemplate>("LIST")` :p

Comment: I've updated my post to explain more in detail what I mean :) Still, thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Try specifying the template parameter like in my comment

Comment: Same unfortunately :/ null

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what items you have in your list. `Bundle` has a couple methods that allow you to place lists in it, for example [`putIntegerArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#putIntegerArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.Integer%3E)) and [`putStringArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#putStringArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)). If you need to use a custom type, you can make it `Parcelable` and use [`putParcelableArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)).

Of course, all these methods as their name suggest take `ArrayList` instances specifically, not just any `MutableList`. So you can either change all your `MutableList` usages to use `ArrayList` instead, or you can create a new `ArrayList` from your existing `MutableList` when you're putting it in the bundle:

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("key", ArrayList(myParcelableList))
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that datatype is an object, see above. Could you elaborate on the parcelable part?

Comment: Use [`@Parcelize`](https://proandroiddev.com/parcelable-in-kotlin-here-comes-parcelize-b998d5a5fcac).

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of recipeArray? You can put various kinds of ArrayList (not List!), including Integers, CharSequences, Strings, and, most generally, Parcelables. See the docs for the full API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle